# Error when configuring database connection from HashiCorp Vault to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to configure a database connection from HashiCorp Vault running on a Hyper-V VM (192.168.50.141), to a MySQL database running on the Windows host machine (192.168.50.103).

The path to the MysqL executable service on the host machine is `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80`, so I make changes to the `my.ini` file as follows:

```
[mysqld]
ssl_ca=ca.pem
ssl_cert=server-cert.pem
ssl_key=server-key.pem
require_secure_transport=ON
```

The PEM files referred to are the ones that were automatically created by MySQL upon installation, and they reside in the folder `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data`.

Once I restart my MySQL service, I create a user as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'vaultuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'vaultpass' REQUIRE ssl;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON amdb.* TO 'vaultuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* to 'vaultuser'@'%';
CREATE USER 'vaultuser'@'192.168.50.141' IDENTIFIED BY 'vaultpass' REQUIRE ssl;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON amdb.* TO 'vaultuser'@'192.168.50.141' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* to 'vaultuser'@'192.168.50.141';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

On my VM, I get an error when I run `mysql -h 192.168.50.103 -P 3306 -uvaultuser -pvaultpass --ssl-mode=DISABLED` (password embedded purely for demonstration purposes), and no errors when I remove the `--ssl-mode` option, or change it to `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED`, so it seems that my connection is correct.

Referring to https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/secrets/databases/mysql-maria under "Client x509 Certificate Authentication", I get an error when I configure my database connection in HashiCorp Vault like this:

```
vault write database/config/my-mysql-database \
    plugin_name=mysql-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="my-role" \
    connection_url="{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(192.168.50.103:3306)/mydb" \
    username=vaultuser \
    password=vaultpass \
    tls_certificate_key=@public_key.pem \
    tls_ca=@ca.pem
```

For `tls_certificate_key` I tried all the other files, but all of them came back with errors, so I am not sure if it has anything to do with my connection URL? Or is there a problem with my procedure from earlier?